# Bug? - Wallpaper thumbnails not shown (settings/switchboard)

Tags: release-loki, wallpaper, switchboard

I have an issue on Loki where in the settings/switchboard menu under "system settings/desktop/wallpaper" where the thumbnail previews are not displayed; i an still change the wallpaper however. Not a major issue but definitely annoying. See a GIF capture of it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj4Qt.jpg)
Cheers, Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, now [reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629597). (We won't be able to offer more than a jury-rigged solution around it as the main issue is fixing the bug.) If you're willing, subscribe to that bug report and add more details (computer model, graphics card information) so that someone can help address the bug. Also, does this bug recur even after restarting your computer?